# How to exclude a node in OData

Tags: json, odata

I have a Odata response structure as below,

```
{
"value": [{
    "a": "10",
    "b": "10",
    "c": "10",
    "Description": null,
    "ExtendedValues": [{
        "x1": "val1",
        "y1": "val2",
        "z1": "val3"
    },
    {
        "x2": "val1",
        "y2": "val2",
        "z2": "val3"
    },
    {
        "x3": "val1",
        "y3": "val2",
        "z3": "val3"
    },
    ],
}]
```

}

I just want to know if there is a way to exclude a specific node from the response. For ex i need to exclude ExtendedValues from the response. Although i could do it by using $select and provide all the required properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do so:

1 Use IgnoreDataMember in ConventionModelBuilder. In the `WebApiConfig.cs` file

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntityType<Person>().Ignore(p => p.Description);
```

Then the property Description will be excluded, BUT it will also disappear in $metadata

2 You can always make such thing work by defining an unbound function to return the value you like. Please refer the [sample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataFunctionSample)

3 If you have a lot of business logic, you may try RESTier -- a framework built on Web API OData and makes business logic easy to implement. More can be seen at http://odata.github.io/RESTier/. You can follow the tutorial of Getting-started 2, *entity set filter*. But currently, RESTier is still a preview version.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think my question was not clear ,what i am asking is if there are any operation available in Odata spec which says the operation to exlude few params from response . for Ex, $select shall allow us to choose the feilds we need. I need something like $exclude.I could not find one in the http://www.odata.org/

Comment: So you mean in OData protocol, if there is something like $exclude ? Well then maybe the answer is no, at least in currently V4 version. But still, I'd like to know your reasons that you thing there should be a $exclude in the protocol.